# Not able to modify $PATH on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, bash

i just want to start with developing Android Apps on my new mac. Therefore i have to add platform-tools and tools from the Eclipsebundle to my $PATH.

The first thing i did was to add these two folders on my local Administrator-Account which worked fine with the command:

```
echo 'export PATH=/Users/myname/Desktop/adtbundle/sdk/platform-tools:"$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
echo 'export PATH=/Users/myname/Desktop/adtbundle/sdk/tools:"$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
```

So, then i added the MacMini into our Company-Domain and logged in with my Account which is saved in our active directory.

I opened up the Terminal again and typed the two commands, but after that, while i want to verify my new $PATH (`echo $PATH`), my $PATH didn't change. Just the standard folders are in it.

I looked for another How-To to edit the $PATH and tryed it like this:

```
cd

nano .bash_profile
```

in my .bash_profile i added:

```
export PATH="/Users/myname/Desktop/adtbundle/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/myname/Desktop/adtbundle/sdk/tools:$PATH"
```

saved all with `control + o` confirmed the name by pressing `return` and then exit nano by clicking `control + x`

tryed to verify my new $PATH -> it did not change and my bash_profile is empty again - can someone tell me, what i did wrong?

**THIS WORKED FOR ME**
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/

Comment: Btw.: Thanks for edit and sorry, i havent seen that i did not mark my lines of code one time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you add path to .bash_profile quit the terminal and open it again. the try to echo $PATH.
It worked for me. else you can add path to /etc/profile.

Answer (score 3):

After editing .bash_profile, refresh the bash enviroment by restarting Terminal or typing the following command:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

'[source](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html)' command will execute the contents of the argument supplied.